# Samsung Galaxy S3 Stuck at Samsung Logo

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3

Please help my phone won't start and keeps restarting. I was playing COC and I think my phone is overused.

I tried to remove the battery then press hold the button for 30 seconds. Then test my phone again but nothing happened.

I tried press hold the Home + Volume Up+ Power On button option then Select factory reset/wipe data. But it doesn't continue.

I don't know if the Power button is stuck.

Then I have no choice, I consult to technician to fix my phone. Then the technician told me my phone was grounded. Then I thought my phone will be fixed. Then After 3 days the technician told me he can't find the grounded and telling me I need to buy a new board of Samsung S3. I refused to buy a new board.

Can I still fix my phone?

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me. I tried to re-flash its firmware then finally it just turned off and cannot power on again. The technician also gave up and said the motherboard is beyond repair. I recall that I overused it and maybe my very cold room generated some moist inside the phone short-circuiting the motherboard.

Comment: Nice theory. I think it the same scenario what happen to my phone. I used Air Conditioner to my room. Did you ever get it fixed?

Comment: Nope. I agree with the technician that it is beyond repair.